# count_substring method not returning number of all substrings

Tags: python-3.x

Apologies for my incoherent-ish question, i simply do not know how to phrase it better.
So basically i have been tasked with outputting the number of occurences a substring appears in a string.
eg. "CDC" would appear twice in "ABCDCDC" and hence the correct output to the function i create would be the integer 2. However, my code below:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].startswith(sub_string):
            count += 1


    return count
```

does not seem to return the correct output of 2 when the command of

```
print(count_substring("ABCDCDC", "CDC"))
```

is given.
Can someone please help?

Comment: small change in if like `if string[i:]`

Comment: @PSKP thanks a lot this works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = sum(1 for i in range(len(string))  
         if string.startswith(sub_string, i))
    return count
```

this works for me